# One row per column with column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

**background**

I am trying to create an SSRS report which will run `select *` on a table passed in as a parameter and display all the data from that table. As I understand it, I can't use a table for this. I want to use a pivot table to achieve this.

`select * from @table` will return something like this (from the adventureworks DB)

[image: <code>select * from person.person</code>]

I want to display the date in this format:

[image: Example output format]

**Question**

How do I achieve this? I looked at using PIVOT/UNPIVOT, but all the examples I've seen use static column names and aggregates.

I won't know the column names at design time (or run time), I'm assuming I will need column headers like 'table name', 'value1', 'value2' etc?

**Limitations**

I won't have access to create stored procedures. Ideally, the report should be able to be run entirely from SSRS without having to create new tables etc.

Performance is not a concern.

**Edit**

Editing to add some clarity. The column names in the example above are only an example. The @table parameter could be any table, column names won't be know at design time. The column names could be col1, col2, or name, address... etc.

Comment: Interesting question (or three). I can give you a solution to the pivot/unpivot bit but not the dynamic dataset creation. If you want to raise another question just on the pivot unpivot bit I will post my solution.

Comment: Just as a note on the adventureworks person table the dataset result is pretty quick but the report rendering takes an age (but it does eventually produce all the business entities).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a normal tablix, with a column group on `BusinessEntityID`

- Create a normal tablix.
- Remove the row group (group only)
- Insert a new parent column group, grouped by BusinessEntityID
- Delete the top row (row only)
- Add each of the row titles in, as per your suggested output
- Add each of the values in the second column

[image: Like this]

Comment: I dont think this is going to work. The column names in my question are there purely as an example, they could be anything, from any table. I'll update the question to make this clearer.